Creating a mask with pure white/black pixels without any grayscale pixels (Photoshop)
I am trying to make a mask layer with only pure white and black pixels, namely without any grey pixels. I have a selection and I would like to fill it with white inside and black outside, without gray pixels of different shades on the border. I have tried to increase the brightness, contrast, set curves, levels, but I cannot get the only white and black pixels.


Hi.  An alpha channel is not a layer mask.  What is your goal here, what are you trying to achieve?  What is the image you are starting with?  Layer masks can be adjusted to remove anti-aliasing, for example using a Threshold adjustment is a pretty easy way.

Hi, thanks. Oh, yes, I meant an alpha channel, not a layer. The image I am working with is a leaf texture on the black background, and the alpha channel is used to make the background transparent in game. My goal is leaving only white and black pixels on the alpha channel, and look if it helps to remove a white halo around a leaf, although I am not sure it is the reason. It is related to my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78775427/halo-around-texture-with-alpha-channel

You can apply a threshold adjustment to the alpha channel too.  Just deselect everything. Select the alpha channel in the channels panel, and do Image > Adjustments > Threshold. Move the slider until  you get the result you want.

Thanks a lot. It worked, namely I got only white and black pixels (after deselecting). (Sadly, it did not help with a white halo around texture, but it is different.)

When you first make your selection, do Select > Modify > Contract. Type in 1px, or more if you want. This will contract the selection a little.
